# Is it possible to use a dynamic hostname in PutTCP?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a simple flow that is supposed to do the following:

- Listen to `http://10.0.0.2:8100/printlabels/<ip address>` for POST requests
- Send the contents body as is to a printer server at `<ip address>` port 9100.
- Respond with success or error

My solution is to accept http requests via **HandleHttpRequests** Flow. Default Settings.

On success, the next flow is **PutTCP** that has Port: 9100 and Hostname: `${http.request.uri:substringAfterLast('/'):trim()}`

Finally a 200 or 500 status response is sent to the client via **HandleHttpResponse**.

The problem is that PutTCP EL Expressions are limited only to the Variable Registry and cannot use Flow File variables at all. So the above expression is always null.

Is there any way to pass the hostname to the **PutTCP** Processor from a previous processor?

Answer (score 1):

No, PutTCP does not support reading FF attributes to change the destination host.

You could use ExecuteScript and use Python or Groovy to handle creating a dynamic TCP socket instead.